# Cakephp installation and root directory

Tags: cakephp

I am working through the [cakephp installation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html) for production use and I have a problem. I use hostmonster, so this is a shared server using a LAMP stack. The documentation asks you to change the Root Directory as shown:

```
DocumentRoot /cake_install/app/webroot
```

To do this, I added the following statements to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cake_install/app/webroot/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This resulted in the error below:

```
Error: The view for AppController::webroot() was not found.
```

When I navigate to www.example.com I am taken to the proper address, but there are errors. These errors disappear if I add an index.php to either the address or obviously to the rewrite rule.

So, what am I doing wrong here? Is the documentation incorrect in that the rewrite rule should have the additional index.php, should be address work without it, or is there something wrong somewhere else?

Update: The second part of the errors says:

```
Error: Confirm you have created the file: /home2/cadwolfc/public_html/cake_install/app/View/App/webroot.ctp
```

The version of cake that I downloaded did not have anything the /app/View folder. When I created the /App/webroot.ctp file it got rid of the errors, but it overrides all other view calls.

Comment: I'd have to guess 'cake_install' is something you change.  Provide the link to the hostmonster instructions you've used?

Comment: There are no hostmonster instructions for anything. They seem to take a great deal of pride in this.

The cake_install is just the name of a folder and follows the cake manual.

Comment: You don't need to set DocumentRoot on Hostmonster.  I use them too and haven't had any issues.  Likely just incorrect paths in your webroot/index.php file

Comment: I should add that the error also says ;

Error: Confirm you have created the file: /home2/cadwolfc/public_html/cake_install/app/View/App/webroot.ctp

However, when I create that file it becomes the only view that shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting provider has not enabled mod_rewrite. Then you would need to delete the .htaccess files

- /.htaccess
- /app/.htaccess
- /app/webroot/.htaccess

If I am wrong and there is nothing wrong with mod_rewrite then you should edit your htaccess file and do something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Mod_Rewrite. When I navigate to www.example.com, I am taken to the proper path that I dictate. However, it is looking for a view that doesn't exist and I don't know why. When I go directly to the index.php page, it works fine.

Comment: Ok, in that case try replacing the content of your .htaccess file with the content I provided.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this is what you're looking for:  [HostMonster - How to host the Primary Domain from a subfolder (.htaccess)](https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/347)

Answer (score 0):

On most shared hosts, you can't change the document root. Since [hostmonster has mod_rewrite](https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/94) there are no special steps for installing cake on hostmonster. There are several ways to install cake - all of them are valid on hostmonster.

### Use a development install

The simplest way to set up an application is to use a development install i.e. so the following folder structure exists:

```
/home2/cadwolfc/public_html/app
/home2/cadwolfc/public_html/lib
/home2/cadwolfc/public_html/plugins
/home2/cadwolfc/public_html/vendors
/home2/cadwolfc/public_html/.htaccess
/home2/cadwolfc/public_html/index.php
```

Don't edit [any of the](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/.htaccess) [.htaccess](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/app/.htaccess) [files](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/app/webroot/.htaccess) unless a specific problem is encountered, or a specific requirement needs to be met. This can be achieved very easily with the following commands or equivalent:

```
cd /home2/cadwolfc
mv public_html old_public
git clone https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git public_html
```

### Or symlink the document root

Alternatively put your files anywhere on the server, and just symlink the webroot:

```
/home2/cadwolfc/anywhere/app
/home2/cadwolfc/anywhere/lib
/home2/cadwolfc/anywhere/plugins
/home2/cadwolfc/anywhere/vendors
/home2/cadwolfc/anywhere/.htaccess
/home2/cadwolfc/anywhere/index.php
/home2/cadwolfc/public_html -> ../anywhere/app/webroot
```

In this way only the webroot is public and only the [webroot .htaccess file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/app/webroot/.htaccess) is relevant.

### Or copy/move the webroot

Alternatively put your files anywhere but *move* the webroot to the document root. Then update [the root constant](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/app/webroot/index.php#L36-L42) to point at where the source files are:

```
// app/webroot/index.php
/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', '/home2/cadwolfc/overhere';
}
```

### What does cake_install mean?

In [Cake's documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html), `cake_install` is explained as follows:

> For the purposes of this example, we assume you chose to install CakePHP into /cake_install.

It's just an example. **However**, it's an example used in the "production install" section, a production install doesn't have all or the application files inside the document root. Setting up a "production install" with the source files inside the document root is not a production install, it's a custom development install (bringing with it custom problems).

Therefore the logical choice is (both of which are usable/secure with mod_rewrite):

- Use a standard development install
- use an *actual* production install

But not a hybrid of the two =)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was definitely confused by the cake_install. I have since moved the cake folder above the public_html folder and the app folder out of the cake folder and into the same place as the cake folder. The contents of the webroot folder are in the public_html but the webroot folder itself is still in the app folder. 

I am confused by the multiple index.php files that now exist. Are you saying that the index.php that matters is the one in the app/webroot/ folder? Also, I wasn't aware that the root needed to be /home2/cadwolfc instead of cadwolf.com?

Comment: the path `home2/cadwolfcp` is used in the question - I don't use hostmonster, I'm not suggesting the path to the document root is completely wrong. I think above all you are over thinking how to install CakePHP - you need mod rewrite (you already have it, and even if you ddin't it's just configuration to get CakePHP to work) and there is nothing specific to your host that means installation requires any specific steps. Use a standard install, and begin developing your application.